# Use courier and newtxtext together

Tags: fonts

I want to use two different monospaced fonts in one and the same document.

However, when I write `\texttt{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}` using `\usepackage{courier}`, I can get figure 2 but cannot get figure 1.

In contrast, when I write `\texttt{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}` using  `\usepackage{newtxtext}`, I can get figure 1 but cannot get figure 2.

So, how to generate the two figures in the same article?

Figure 1:

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2:

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to be able to use two different monospaced fonts in one and the same document?

Comment: @Mico Yes, thanks for the clear description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, although it's not really clear why you want this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\DeclareRobustCommand\crfamily{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcr}{\crfamily}

\begin{document}

\texttt{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

\textcr{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

[image]